# PHP Parsing Question

Tags: php, xml, parsing

If I am parsing an rss feed with php and xml, how can I parse more than one feed using one `fopen` statement. I am currently storing the feeds in different variables, and my `fopen` statement looks like this:

```
$fp=fopen($feedzero, $feedone, $feedtwo, "r")
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

> fopen() expects parameter 4 to be resource, string given

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You'll have to open the files using separate handles and iterate over them separately.

```
$feedoneFp = fopen($feedone, 'r');
$feedtwoFp = fopen($feedtwo, 'r');
$feedthreeFp = fopen($feedthree, 'r');
```

Comment: That works. Thank you deceze. By the way, I'm loving the mustache.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php explains a bit about fopen function. also using http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.consuming-rss.html would save you from bug hunting

Answer (score 0):

fopen expects parameter 4 to be a resource.  You gave it a string.  It looks like you may have meant to pass in a mode representing "read-only".  Mode is the 2nd parameter, not the 4th.